# How REST call should look like?

Tags: rest, url, spring-rest

I my system, there are Employees, Designation, DesignationHierarchy. And Based on DesignationHierarchy I have EmployeeHierarchy.

I have a following REST URLs,

To access Employee,

```
//employees/:empployeeNo
```

To access Designation

```
//designations/:designationNo
```

To get Employee with Designation,

```
//employees/:employeeNo/designations/:designation/:id    //Here I have used id of EmployeeDesignation resource because there are multiple entries for that employee with same designation for different timespans
```

When I say Hierarchy, it is NOT hierarchy of Employee rather Hierarchy of EmployeeDesignation resource.

To update Employee Hierarchy I have used,

```
//employees/:empNo/designations/:designation/:id/hierarchy
```

I also need a rest call to view graph of Employee Hierarchy on date,
I have use following URL,

```
/employee/:employeeNo/designations/:designation/Hierarchy/graph?date=
```

I have created subresource graph under hierarchy.

These REST URLs are correct according to standard convensions?

Please correct me if wrong !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the URIs you have suggested are perfectly valid and correct when it comes to RESTful architectural style.

The only thing I that comes to my head is that is not good practice to use too long URIs. I mean that in some cases you can shorten:

```
/res1/{ID1}/res2/{ID2}/res3/{ID3}/
```

to e.g.:

```
/res3/{ID3}/
```

Whereas it may not make a great sense in this particular example you've provided however it's worth to remember about avoid URIs that are too long.

Comment: Regarding shortening url, I thought about that and for Hierarchy resource I thought to make it as main resource. Say to _update_ hierarchy `//hierarchy/:employeeDesignationId`  and to _get graph_ `//hierarchy/graph`. Does that sounds valid?

Comment: @sillyquestions, yes, it does make sense definitely.